# Python Pandas "Error: Could not install packages due to an OSError: No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, geopandas, oserror

```
System:Win10
IDE: VSCode
Python path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3
```

while trying to install pandas and geopandas via VSCode terminal to run Jupyter Notebook, I encountered issues, so I created a conda environment and installed pandas and geopandas via Command Prompt and they were successful. Now the Jupyter Notebook worked, by my pythonfiles.py) on VSCode can't find pandas.

```
> PS C:\Users\user\folder> python pythonfile.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "pythonfile.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>
```

when I check "pip list" in VSCode, resulted:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------------------
asn1crypto      0.23.0
certifi         2017.11.5
cffi            1.11.2
chardet         3.0.4
conda           4.3.31
cryptography    2.1.4
idna            2.6
menuinst        1.4.10
numpy           1.19.5
pip             21.0.1
pycosat         0.6.3
pycparser       2.18
pyOpenSSL       17.5.0
PySocks         1.6.7
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2021.1
pywin32         221
requests        2.18.4
ruamel-yaml     0.11.14
setuptools      36.5.0.post20170921
six             1.11.0
urllib3         1.22
wheel           0.30.0
win-inet-pton   1.0.1
wincertstore    0.2
```

when I check pip list in Command Prompt, resulted

```
(env1) C:\Users\user>pip list
Package          Version
---------------- -------------------
attrs            20.3.0
backcall         0.2.0
certifi          2020.12.5
chardet          4.0.0
click            7.1.2
click-plugins    1.1.1
cligj            0.7.1
colorama         0.4.4
cycler           0.10.0
decorator        4.4.2
Fiona            1.8.18
GDAL             3.2.2
geopandas        0.9.0
idna             2.10
ipykernel        5.5.0
ipython          7.18.1
ipython-genutils 0.2.0
jedi             0.17.2
jupyter-client   6.1.7
jupyter-core     4.6.3
kiwisolver       1.3.1
matplotlib       3.3.4
munch            2.5.0
numpy            1.20.1
pandas           1.2.3
parso            0.7.0
pickleshare      0.7.5
Pillow           8.1.2
pip              21.0.1
prompt-toolkit   3.0.8
Pygments         2.7.1
pyparsing        2.4.7
pyproj           3.0.1
python-dateutil  2.8.1
pytz             2021.1
pywin32          227
pyzmq            19.0.2
requests         2.25.1
setuptools       52.0.0.post20210125
Shapely          1.7.1
six              1.15.0
tornado          6.0.4
traitlets        5.0.5
urllib3          1.26.4
wcwidth          0.2.5
wheel            0.36.2
wincertstore     0.2
```

seems pandas and geopandas are installed in the environment, however, running the pythoncode.py still returned:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\user\folder\pythonfile.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>
```

when I return to VSCode and try to install pandas again, I get the following error:

> 

```
> PS C:\Users\user\folder> pip install pandas Collecting pandas  
> Using cached pandas-1.1.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (8.7 MB)
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
> (from pandas) (1.19.5) Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
> (from pandas) (2021.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
> (from pandas) (2.8.1) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
> (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.11.0) ERROR: Could not
> install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory:'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2021.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

how can I make pandas and geopandas work ?

Comment: is pandas installed in your [miniconda](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html)  env?

Comment: I suppose if it in the (env1) list (see copy under "when I check pip list in Command Prompt") it should be installed, its in the pip list. I also have installed it via Command Prompt using pip, and it was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the python used by the internal terminal of VS Code is different from the python environment you currently select in VS Code (shown in the lower left corner of VS Code).

I noticed that you are using the powershell terminal, which does not automatically activate the conda environment by default in VS Code.

1. Please select conda environment in VS Code, it will be displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code. (`F1`, `Python: Select Interpreter`)
2. Please enter "`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process`" in the VS Code terminal, and then reopen the VS Code terminal (Ctrl+Shift+`). When using the command "python --version", the python version it displays is the same as the one displayed in the lower left corner.

   [image]
3. If the module is not installed in this environment, please follow it. (`pip install pandas`)

Update:

In addition, please try to use other terminals, such as the 'cmd' terminal. [Can I use Cmder's shell with the terminal on Windows?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows)

Reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).

Comment: after trying the method above, I got the following msg: 
`ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(339): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.59.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running conda clean --packages may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.`


`CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running conda clean --packages may resolve your problem.`

Comment: @9StoriesAround -Have you tried using other terminals, such as 'cmd'? [use Cmder's shell with the terminal on Windows.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows)

Comment: running the code from cmd works, does it mean that I would have to stick to cmd in the future?

Comment: @9StoriesAround  -Since the internal terminal of VS Code uses the terminal integrated from the system, if you want to use powershell, please check whether the powershell terminal of the system is available outside of VS Code.